# Typescript Method Decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code

```
function changeFunc() {
    return function(target: any, title: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {

        descriptor.value = function () {
            console.log(this.name);
        };

        return descriptor;

    }
}


class Man {
    name: string = "asdsds";

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @changeFunc()
    getName() {
        console.log("Hello");
    }

}


var man = new Man('Manos Serifios');
man.getName();
```

In other words i try (with the decorator) to change 
the method

```
getName() {  
    console.log("Hello");  
}
```

with this

```
function () {
    console.log(this.name);
}
```

but this.name evaluated as undefined.

If i console log the "this" it seems that is the right(instance man).

Comment: maybe `descriptor.value = function () { console.log(target.name); };`. I am just guessing and have no experience with typescript decorators

Comment: @2pha no, i tried it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have the context of a specific *object instance* inside the decorator method. The parameters are the following (from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html):

> **Either the constructor function of the class for a static member, or the prototype of the class for an instance member**.
>
> The name of the member.
>
> The Property Descriptor for the member.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a little Hack.
Replace your code

```
descriptor.value = function () {
  console.log(this.name);
};
```

with this nice trick:

```
descriptor.value = function () {
  // Hack 
  const self = this as Man;
  console.log(self.name);
};
```

Comment: but if your decorator is used on hundreds of classes?  and you would have to have your class defined in your decorator file and they are codependent.

Answer (score 0):

@hackerman's answer worked for me, as it seems to just be a typing issue.
An alternative solution would be to actively define the type of `this` for that function:

```
descriptor.value = function (this: Man) {
  console.log(this.name);
};
```