# TypeScript property decorator : access to other properties

Tags: typescript, object, properties, decorator

I have a class Point like this :

```
class Point {
    @test('admin') x: number = 6

    y: number = 5
}
```

With Test decorator :

```
function test(myValue: string) {
    function t(target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: 
    TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
        //want to test y value > x value 
    }
return <any>t
}
```

In my test I want to check y value for exemple throw an error if x < y

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217146/typescript-method-decorator/48222970#48222970).

> You don't have the context of a specific *object instance* inside the decorator method. The parameters are the following (from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html):
>
> > **Either the constructor function of the class for a static member, or the prototype of the class for an instance member**.
> >
> > The name of the member.
> >
> > The Property Descriptor for the member.

Comment: Just fyi, your `this one` link refers to an edit of an answer.

Comment: hey, thanks :) don't know how this happened, it was a pretty old answer

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it directly from the decorator function. You can, however, use the decorator function to redefine the getter and setter for the property, and access the context object passed into them from there:

```
class Point {
    @test() x: number;

    y: number;
    
    constructor(x: any, y: any) {
      this.y = y; // Doing this first since the test is on the x setter
      this.x = x;
    }
}

function test() {
  function t(target: Object, propertyKey: string) {
    //want to test y value > x value 
    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
      set: function(this, newVal) {
        if (this.y > newVal)
          this._x = newVal;
        else
          throw new Error(`${this.y} is not greater than ${newVal}!`);
      },
      get: function() {
        return this._x;
      }
    });
  };
  return t;
}

try {
  let a = new Point(1, 2);
  console.log(`a = ${a.x}`);
}
catch (ex) {
  console.log(ex);
}

try {
  let b = new Point(3, 2);
  console.log(`b = ${b.x}`);
}
catch (ex) {
  console.log(ex);
}
```

[TypescriptLang Snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKD2BLAdgF2gbwFDV9AAqgKYSoAUAlNAB4Bc0yArgLYBGRATgNxY54Ce9Jm04880PrmDxkpDo2Cp4HMnWhhk-ADTRB6zVWzjcqABaIIAOn7QAvLq7QA9E+gARJMgDm0MxegAZogcpNAQKMBEvqZRxKH+MtFR1GFEqMQcknh+Vin21GJ4AL5YJVgBjMiKiIlx5IZ8FVWoNci+ZKhgHF5p9ADyrABWRIo6AA4c8GOcqPwA0kR6ciheDeIuAO4a6Eq+JOg2AG5gIIxRAHw00MenUVkDw4qWACZEQchEsJPTHLMdXT1UONvjN5osdEZjBBeoFKtUZB1zBAdB8NgA1E5rYy4RABaCIizWaCXVEYkAULLYnKWAD6eQYRHRJ0K2KIIGhlOMZkmGwZvIAohxJioAAYAEgw1P4RWg-mQ8HQXg4RDAGWiGmgEtJJyKAEIRRQWcUtJzAfQmvDkJRMJzcMrUIwOG1qXSjbgSuIioa+EVCvbHc6eGVUBwbJCQGl1HY+XBPOQAIw6ABM3qkMgg8AjlhA8C8ZBFYGjErAlmoRQNQawwFVwFM+KI1Cx0lkmaI2dzZAb3uDoZtuAj6FY0dRsZQ5AAzMnU9Bmxmszm8yKh-YJaxS+Xu1Wa3XO42+zP06323mu0GgA)

Comment: This is totally the right thing, even if it's not particularly intuitive. Can anyone explain why this works? `Object.defineProperty` takes the object you're modifying as a parameter, so why is it that `target` is not the instance?

Comment: @JeffPutz: If I understand your question correctly, the `target` that is passed into the decorator function isn't the final object, but the prototype for the all future objects that will be created based on the definition. The final instance is the one that actually calls the getter/setter. Does that help?

Comment: I think I understand, and the prototype is in fact a unique derivative of the instance, not the original class definition, right? In other words, in your example, checking the `x` or `y` properties in this way from other instances will result in their instance values, yes?

Comment: It's kind of like a.... pre-instance? That future instances will be based on. I think the best way to describe is with another problem I had with them: There are patterns that advise caching the instance value in a local variable inside the function I've called `t` here. This works as long as you only ever have one instance of the property. If you need multiple concurrent instances, then you find that they all have the same value, because they are all resolving to that same instance of function `t`.

Comment: My resolution of this was to add another layer of `Object.defineProperty` inside this `set` function, with the caching variable declared just before that. This `set` effectively becomes a persistent `init` function that replaces itself with the instance-specific `set` function on each new instance as the new instance's `set` is called, and it now has its own privately scoped cached variable within the faux `init`.

Comment: Not sure if that made what's going on more or less clear.

Comment: a little of both, which is fine, and importantly, what I want to do in this realm works as intended. I'm managing some state and sending callbacks, so I've got only one instance of these state boxes, but I still want to understand what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

No, according to the [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-evaluation), decorators are evaluated and called in the following order during object initialization:

> 1. Parameter Decorators, followed by Method, Accessor, or Property Decorators are applied for each instance member. 2. Parameter Decorators, followed by Method, Accessor, or Property Decorators are applied for each static member. 3. Parameter Decorators are applied for the constructor. 4.
>    Class Decorators are applied for the class.

The ["complete guide"](https://saul-mirone.github.io/a-complete-guide-to-typescript-decorator/) that they link to also elaborates on how this ties into the initialization of the object as a whole. In short, the constructor for the object (and by association your inline assignment of `y = 3`) has not yet been called by the time that `@test('admin')` is called. I've tested this locally and confirmed.