# Javascript class method decorator access to this

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a class

```
class Service {
    authenticated = false;

    login() {
        // login
        this.authenticated = true;
    }

    unauthenticatedMethod() {
        // everyone should have access
    }

    authenticatedMethod() {
        // only if authenticated  = true
    }
}
```

I'd like to have a decorator `@authenticated` that I can add to `authenticatedMethod` method to check for `authenticated` variable.

Comment: you'll want to use Flow probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently js in browsers not support decorators [yet](https://itnext.io/a-minimal-guide-to-ecmascript-decorators-55b70338215e) - however you can use typescript to have [decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) - however ts decorators don't have access to `this` ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48300101/860099));