# TypeScript method decorator -- `this` with noImplicitThis enabled

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to write a simple method decorator, that does some simple logic before calling the original method. All the examples I could find boil down to calling `originalMethod.apply(this, args)` at the end -- but with `noImplicitThis` enabled in `tsconfig.json`, I get the following error:

```
[eval].ts(1,224): error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
```

I tried working around by calling `originalMethod.apply(this as any, args)`, but the error persists.

**Question:** Are there any workarounds to call the original method, **without** disabling `noImplicitThis` for the whole project?

---

Minimal example -- works with `noImplicitAny` disabled:

```
function logBeforeCall1(): originalMethodDecorator {
    return function(
        target: any,
        propertyKey: string | symbol,
        descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
    ): PropertyDescriptor {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = (...args: any[]) => {
            console.log('hello!');
            return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        };
        return descriptor;
    };
}

class Test1 {
    private num: number = 1;

    @logBeforeCall1()
    test(next: number): void {
        console.log(this.num, '->', next);
        this.num = next;
    }
}
```

---

- I already know that decorators don't have access to a specific object instance (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217146/typescript-method-decorator)), but using `this` in the above example works
- Event the official docs on decorators use the construction from my example (see the [Property Decorators section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators)), so it *works*, but conflicts with `noImplicitThis` compiler option...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @Grassator for inspiration -- this is a version that works. I don't believe this can be done type-safely in the current state of TypeScript though.

```
function logBeforeCall2(): originalMethodDecorator {
    return function(
        target: any,
        propertyKey: string | symbol,
        descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
    ): PropertyDescriptor {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = function(this: any, ...args: any[]): any {
            console.log('hello!');
            return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        };
        return descriptor;
    };
}
```

...

```
> t2.test(5)
hello!
1 '->' 5
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can really get type safety, but if you just want to get rid of type error you can explicitly say that `this: any` (3rd line):

```
function logBeforeCall1() {
  return function (
    this: any,
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
  ): PropertyDescriptor {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = (...args: any[]) => {
      console.log('hello!');
      return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

Comment: This compiles, but fails at runtime: `   test(next) { console.log(this.num, '->', next); this.num = next; }`  -> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'num' of undefined
        at test ([eval].ts:5:35)`

Comment: But, inspired by your answer, I found a solution -- the `this` argument needs to be added to the actual substituted method, not the decorator function.